# Strange data when reading from usb serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to read data from a serialport. When i use USB adapters i get junk instead of what is sendt.

What i expect (And get with a normal serialport)

```
 0001 C0  23:33:41.9114 00
 0001 C1  23:34:17.8207 00
 0001 RT  00:00:35.90   00
n0002
 0002 C0  23:34:32.8372 00
 0002 C1  23:42:36.2617 00
 0002 RT  00:08:03.42   00
n0003
 0003 C0  23:42:44.3947 00
```

What i get when connected through a USB serial port (0x00 0x3F ...)

```
003F003F783F003F003F003F003F003F
003F003F003F003F003F3F3F3F003F00
3F3F78003F003F003F003F003F780000
3F003F783F003F003F003F003F003F00
3F003F003F003F003F3F3F3F003F003F
3F78003F003F00
```

Also when i use Putty to connect it displays correct texte even through USB serial port.

What can be wrong here? How does Putty "fix" the corrupt data.

Edit: Added code used for reading

```
    SerialPort p = new SerialPort(Conf.Value("ExternalClockPort"), int.Parse(Conf.Value("ExternalClockBaud")), Parity.None, 8, StopBits.Two);
p.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
p.Open();
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
String command = "";
while (!Done)
{
    int cnt = p.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    File.AppendAllText(this.appDataDirectory + "ExternalClock.log", ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, cnt));
    command = ExternalClock.parseCommand(command + ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, cnt));
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you use to read from the serial port. Do you use ReadLine with some encoding set?

Comment: Added reading code. I use ASCII encoding. The problem is that it behaves differently with different serialports.

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong baudrate / serial port settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you need to register an event `DataRecieved` and read the port data from it. Also, make sure your port initialization values are correct.

```
_sp = new SerialPort(Conf.Value("ExternalClockPort"), int.Parse(Conf.Value("ExternalClockBaud")), Parity.None, 8, StopBits.Two);
_sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);
_sp.Open();


private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int totalBytes = _sp.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[totalBytes];
    _sp.Read(buffer, 0, totalBytes);
}
```

Comment: I do this in its own thread so it doesnt matter that p.Read() blocks. Does the datareceived event do anything with the data?

Comment: It doesn't do anything with the data by itself, it just signals when the port is ready to receive data. You can't read data from a port at any time, you must use the event.

Comment: there is no SerialPort pre-defined class in Java?? To Achive this task in java waht can i need to do?? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer to your question. I had the same problem and the fix was as follows:
My parity was set to Odd instead of Even, and I was having this exact issue up until I changed the parity to Even.

myParity = Parity.Even;